# NoSuchMethodError on new StreamingContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a Streaming context but it keeps throwing exception in the creating StreamingContext line
Here's my code

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Minutes(15))
```

And here's the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.liftedTree1$1(JobGenerator.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.<init>(JobGenerator.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.<init>(JobScheduler.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:76)
    at vn.fpt.fplay.kafka.StreamConsumer$.main(StreamConsumer.scala:19)
    at vn.fpt.fplay.kafka.StreamConsumer.main(StreamConsumer.scala)
```

I've searched everywhere but can't find out what this error is? Does anybody know? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the stack trace says
`org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator` (class in spark streaming) is trying to call a method `org.apache.spark.util.Utils` (class in spark core)

There are two reasons for this.

- Spark Core is not added to your project dependency.
- There's a mismatch of version between spark-core and spark streaming library

Check your sbt / maven and try to add or change to suitable version.

Comment: Thank you, I went in the build.sbt file and changed the version of "spark-streaming" to my sparkVer, which is 3.0.1, it's working now